# Executebatch not working only last rows insert in database

Tags: java, jdbc

I am doing like this but in database last line only update.

I have checked if 20 rows there, all rows are adding at time of addbatch but at the time of executeBatch, in database upadated only last rows only.

```
ArrayList<String> li = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("VL01Data");
Iterator<String> it = li.iterator();
String splitter = request.getAttribute("SPLITTER") != null ?(String)request.getAttribute("SPLITTER"): "!";                       

String QueryIn = "INSERT INTO ......) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";                   

while(it.hasNext()) {
    String value =it.next().toString(); 

    StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(value,splitter);
    String S = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();
    String I = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();              
    String M = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();
    String d = strTok.nextElement().toString();             
    String R = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();              
    String Pu = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();             
             .               
             .                 

    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(QueryIn);
    pstmt.setString(1,e );
    pstmt.setString(2, r);
    pstmt.setString(3, y);
    pstmt.setString(4, d);
    pstmt.setString(5, y);
    pstmt.setString(6, i);  
                 .
                 .
    pstmt.setString(19,f1 );    
    pstmt.setString(20,f2);                 
    pstmt.addBatch();                                           
}

pstmt.executeBatch();               
con.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't re-`prepare` the statement in the loop body. Prepare it once before your loop like

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(QueryIn);

while(it.hasNext()) {
  String value = it.next().toString(); 

  StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(value,splitter);
  String S = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();
  String I = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();                
  String M = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();
  String d = strTok.nextElement().toString();               
  String R = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();                
  String Pu = strTok.nextElement().toString().trim();

  // pstmt=con.prepareStatement(QueryIn);
  // ...
```

when you re-assign the `pstmt` reference by calling `prepareStatement` it loses the previous (batch) *state* (on every loop iteration), so you only get the very last one when you call `executeBatch()`.

Comment: THANKS #ELLiott Frisch